# PHP debugging code formatting

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to enchance my PHP development power and like to introduce code formatting, rectangle selection mode and debugging php.
I have Eclipse XDebug working but code formatting is not working as expected.

Using Netbeans PHP problem with debugging.

Switched to JetBrains PHP Storm problem with debugging.

My environment is Mac OS X with MAMP and a good version of `xdebug.so` (works in Eclipse).

This is in my PHP 5.5.10 version ini file

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=8888
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
```

checked with php --version.

I installed JetBrains browser plugin testing with Chrome. I played with ports.

Hardware is MacBook Pro stand alone debug and testing.

Comment: You haven't really explained what you need help with here: you mention a "problem with debugging" (or perhaps several different problems, since you use the phrase several times?) but you never tell us what that problem is. Similarly, "code formatting is not working as expected": how did you expect it to work, and what happened instead? You could let us keep guessing until we either get lucky or get bored, but it would be better if you explained exactly what you tried to set up, and what problem(s) you had.

Comment: I decided to focus on Netbeans. In eclipse mixed pages won't format so pages with html php and js could not be utoformat.

Comment: In net beans I got waiting for connection without answering.

Comment: Please click edit under the question and clarify what you need rather than adding more titbits as comments.

Comment: I realized this is very difficult to describe exactly what I tried and what my settings are. So I made a screencast to point my problem out. See here http://youtu.be/psYhUQ1X-Pw I hope that helps to help me!.

Comment: adding a comment to a thread is not so good visible generating no real answers.

Comment: Click [this edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24342596/edit). Edit your question to remove irrelevant details and add new details. Then people reading the question may be more able to answer it.